# Calcular dias habiles y no habiles

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo una duda que no se como podria encarar...tengo 2 inputs tipo datetime-local, el usuario debe seleccionar un dia y hora de ingreso y un dia y hora de termino (son cirugias), entonces una cirugía puede comenzar el dia 01 de abril a las 23:00 pm y terminar el dia 02 de abril a las 2:30 am...

Tengo que calcular el total de tiempo que llevo la cirugía (que serian 3:30), comenzó un día hábil VIERNES (dias habiles son de lunes a viernes) pero termino un día no hábil SABADO (dias no habiles son sábado o domingo), ademas los horarios tambien pueden ser habiles (PM) Y NO HABILES (AM)

Por el momento mediante Carbon, tengo una funcion que me permite calcular el tiempo entre los inputs, puedo obtener de forma separada el nombre del dia, el nombre del mes, pero no se como diferenciar entre horas am y pm (para poder definir si fueron horarios habiles y no habiles) y lo de los dias tampoco me doy una idea como hacer...

Este es el codigo que estoy manejando:

```
public function consultaTiempoOcupacion(Request $request){
         //return($request->all());

         $errores = [];
         $exito = [];

         $ingreso = Carbon::parse($request->inicio);
         $salida = Carbon::parse($request->termino);

         //Obtengo los Dias de Ingreso y Salida
         $dia_ingreso = $ingreso->dayName;
         $dia_salida = $salida->dayName;

         //Obtengo el Mes de Ingreso
         $mes_ingreso = $ingreso->monthName;

         //Obtengo el Anio de Ingreso
         $anio_ingreso = $ingreso->year;

         //Obtengo la Hora de Ingreso
         $hora_ingreso = $ingreso->format('H:i');

         //Obtengo la Hora de Salida
         $hora_salida = $salida->format('H:i');

         //Calculo el tiempo del procedimiento
         //$duracion_total = $salida->diffInHours($hora_ingreso);
         $duracion_total = $ingreso->diff($salida)->format('%H:%I:%S');

         //return $duracion_total;


         //VALIDAR QUE LA MAC ESTE ASIGNADA A LA MISMA BODEGA QUE VIENE POR REQUEST
       /*   $cliente  = Cliente::where('rut_cliente', $request->rut)->first(); //0
         //$id_serializacion = $serial->id; */

         if($duracion_total){
             //return "asasas";
             //array_push($errores, 'YA EXISTE UN CLIENTE CON ESTE RUT');
             return response()->json(['exito' => $duracion_total]);

         } else{
             //return "LA SERIE ESTA EN STATUS 1";
             //array_push($errores, 'SERIE NO DISPONIBLE PARA TRANSFERENCIA');
             return response()->json(['data' => 'attached', 'errores' => $errores]);
         }

    }
```

Agradezco desde ya cualquier comentario que pueda orientarme un poco

Comment: la función [date de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) tiene como sacar los AM y PM,  `format('A');`

Comment: Gracias al percer me funcionó, veré si me resulta la distinción de los días hábiles